# Drawing a Projectile Motion Path in Android

Tags: android, physics, draw, gravity, geometric-arc

I asked this question before, but I think I worded it badly and thus did not get any response. I am trying to make an app for android that draws the path of an object in projectile motion. I have the equations to make this work, but for some reason, when I run my program, all I get is 2 connected lines instead of the proper arc. I've been staring at this for hours, can anyone tell me what is happening and what I need to do to fix it? Here is my code:(It also draws the ground, but that part seems to work. It is included because some of the variables used to create the ground are also used in the arc.)

```
float constx = 400;
    float consty = 375;
    float deltx = (float) ProjectileMotionDrawingActivity.dx;
    float delty = (float) ProjectileMotionDrawingActivity.dy;
    float maxDrawingHeight;
    float totwidth;
    float totheight;
    float starty;
    float ydist;
    float cx = canvas.getWidth()/2;
    float cy = 210;
    boolean limiter;

    float vin = (float) ProjectileMotionDrawingActivity.vin;
    float vxd = (float) ProjectileMotionDrawingActivity.vxd;
    float acc = (float) ProjectileMotionDrawingActivity.ac;

    float scaleda;
    float scaledv;
    float scaledvi;



    //Set background color and get paint ready
    canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    Paint linePaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    linePaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);

    //Define maxDrawingHeight
    if(delty >= 0){
        maxDrawingHeight = (float) ProjectileMotionDrawingActivity.mhe;
    }else{
        maxDrawingHeight = (float) (ProjectileMotionDrawingActivity.mhe + Math.abs(delty));
    }

    // Determine whether x or y is limiting factor (true=x, false =y) (For future use if needed)
    if(Math.abs(maxDrawingHeight/deltx) >=consty/constx){
        limiter = false;
    }else{
        limiter = true;
    }

    //set width and height of projectile motion
    if(limiter){
        totwidth = constx;
        totheight = constx*maxDrawingHeight/deltx;
        scaleda = acc*constx/deltx;
        scaledvi = vin*constx/deltx;
        scaledv = vxd*constx/deltx;

    }else{
        totheight = consty;
        totwidth = consty*deltx/maxDrawingHeight;
        scaleda = acc*consty/maxDrawingHeight;
        scaledvi = vin*consty/maxDrawingHeight;
        scaledv = vxd*consty/maxDrawingHeight;
    }

    //height of cliff
    ydist = delty*totheight/maxDrawingHeight;

    //start height
    starty = cy+(totheight/2);

    canvas.drawLine(0, starty, totwidth+35, starty, linePaint);
    canvas.drawLine(totwidth+35, starty, totwidth+35, starty-ydist, linePaint);
    canvas.drawLine(totwidth+35, starty-ydist, 2*cx, starty-ydist, linePaint);

    //Parabola

    float porabx = 35;
    float poraby = starty;
    float porabx2 = 35 + totwidth/50;
    float poraby2 = (float) (starty - scaledvi*porabx2/scaledv-.5*scaleda*Math.pow(porabx2/scaledv,2));

    for(int i=0;i<50;i++){
        canvas.drawLine(porabx, poraby, porabx2, poraby2 , linePaint);

        porabx = porabx2;
        poraby = poraby2;
        porabx2 += totwidth/50;
        poraby2 = (float) (starty - scaledvi*porabx2/scaledv-.5*scaleda*Math.pow(porabx2/scaledv,2));

    }
}
```

Update: After looking at this for a while and trying different numbers, I believe that the first line being drawn is the correct first (1/50) of the arc. For some reason it seems like the there is a problem with the poraby2 variable in the loop.

Comment: My comment on the previous version of this question still stands. If you want to solve this problem, you must put in some effort.

Answer (score 2):

I guess your problem is there:

```
for(int i=0;i<1;i++){
```

You are looping only once ...

Comment: I apologize. I put that there while I was trying to figurre out what was wrong. It actually loops 50 times.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. As it turns out, my problem was only half in the code. First, I had not accounted for the initial vertical offset, which created the first of the two lines. The second problem was the numbers I was putting in. I didn't realize it but I was putting in velocities that were about seventy miles per hour while the projectile was only travelling a couple of feet. This made the path seem straight. And all this time I put in the same numbers for testing consistency. It only took 10 hours to figure that out.